# Rationalize denominator: $\frac{9\sqrt{2}}{1+\sqrt{2}-2\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{10}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{9\sqrt{2}}{1+\sqrt{2}-2\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{10}}$$
I simplified it by making it:
$$\frac{9\sqrt{2}}{(1-\sqrt{10})(1+\sqrt{2})}$$
What do I do next? I am confused what to do because it is multiplication. All of my previous examples were either use square binomial or square subtraction. Here I cant think of anything to get rid of these square roots.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\frac{9\sqrt{2}(1+\sqrt{10})(1-\sqrt{2})}{(1-\sqrt{10})(1+\sqrt{2})(1+\sqrt{10})(1-\sqrt{2})}=$$

$$\frac{9\sqrt{2}(1+\sqrt{10})(1-\sqrt{2})}{(1-10)(1-2)}=$$

$$\sqrt{2}(1+\sqrt{10})(1-\sqrt{2})=...$$

Comment: Wow... It is the same thing. I got confused because of the two brackets. Thanks !